# Why Bedrock ProtocolReader ignores CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

It seems that my Custom `ProtocolReader` ignores `CancellationToken`, also the `result.Cancelled` is always `false`.

I took most of the code from: https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/master/samples/ServerApplication/MyCustomProtocol.cs

Am is missing something?

Here is my `ProtocolReader`:

```
public class CustomProtocolReader : IMessageReader<SocketObject>
{
    public bool TryParseMessage(in ReadOnlySequence<byte> input,
        ref SequencePosition consumed, 
        ref SequencePosition examined, 
        out SocketObject message)
    {
        var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(input);

        var payload = input.Slice(reader.Position, input.Length);
        message = new SocketObject { Buffer = payload.ToArray() };

        consumed = payload.End;
        examined = consumed;

        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is the `ConnectionHandler`:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(2000);

        // this should throw if nothing is received after 2 seconds.
        var result = await reader.ReadAsync(protocol, cts.Token); 

        if (result.IsCompleted || result.IsCanceled)  // this never hits
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Broke or cancelled");
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) // this never gets fired
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
        break;
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Advance();
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**

default `connection.Transport.Input.ReadAsync` works as expected and respects `CancellationToken`.

Comment: One explanation could be that the code does not check whether the cancellation has been requested. The code consuming the `CancellationToken` must check manually if the `IsCancellationRequested` property is set to true and subsequently stop the operation or call the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` method which throws the `OperationCanceledException` in case the `IsCancellationRequested` property is set to true.

Comment: Yeah, But the main question is why `ReadAsync` dose not cancel?

Comment: He just told you an idea, and yes, sometimes the implementations are only looking at begin of method entry (in this example `ReadAsync`) for IsCancellationRequested but ignore them in ongoing procedures within the call itself.

Comment: See `Stream` for an example of this: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,e224b4bec8748849,references

Comment: @Teroneko this seems to be a bug, as `ConnectionHandler` dose not ignore the token at all (so this is not by design).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find the source code of your reader you are using by `reader.ReadAsync(protocol, cts.Token)`. It would be as easy as this to look into the implementation of the reader you are using.

Comment: `reader` is `CustomProtocolReader` (the code is included in the question).

Comment: Nope, that's not true. your `CustomProtocolReader` implements `IMessageReader<TMessage>` and is not the reader you are using. The reader you are using is `ProtocolReader` https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/982f8f7fc97bac983cea297d84bacdd4530e1535/src/Bedrock.Framework/Protocols/ProtocolReader.cs which has methods (the `ReadAsync` method I am talking of) that need your `IMessageReader<SocketObject>` reader. :P (found the sources ^^)

Comment: It is not a bug. Imagine each method that accepts a cancellation token would have to create a seperate task that continuously looks for cancellation request. That would be crazy and makes absolutely no sense. But looking at start of a method once that is about to start the actual task like waiting for buffer input, that costs nearly nothing. =)

Comment: Can you add the actual behavior? What is the state of `result`, when its neither completed nor cancelled, or what is the exception when it's not an `OperationCanceledException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Ohh well.. I've just overlooked [this part](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b8b81a66738bb10ef0790023598396861d92b2c4/src/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/PipeAwaitable.cs#L60). So yes, you should expect the cancellation after 2 seconds and even `ValueTask` should print `IsCancled = true`. :/ I'm afraid, but I don't know about that. I tried to understand the IValueTaskSource.OnCompleted implementation of `Pipe/PipeAwaitable` but it is very complicated. I don't have the time right now.

I will let the answer here because of historical reasons.

> It seems that my Custom ProtocolReader ignores CancellationToken

It does not.

First of all you have to know that `CancellationToken` is not actively doing something. When using `CancellationToken.CancelAfter` it just notifies its origin `CancellationTokenSource` and their children (the cancellation token sources that got created by `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`) to set their `IsCancellationRequested` to true and fires all handlers (registered by `CancellationToken.Register`) in all involved `CancellationTokenSource`'s. It is in your response to listen to a cancellation request by continously looking at `IsCancellationRequested` or by register a handler with `CancellationToken.Register` (see example implementation below).

The deepest subroutine when calling `reader.ReadAsync` is checking one time if the token you passed to `reader.ReadAsync` has been cancellation requested. Let me elaborate this in detail:

I assume that your `reader` of type [ProtocolReader](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/982f8f7fc97bac983cea297d84bacdd4530e1535/src/Bedrock.Framework/Protocols/ProtocolReader.cs) has been created from [connectionContext.CreateReader](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/982f8f7fc97bac983cea297d84bacdd4530e1535/src/Bedrock.Framework/Protocols/Protocol.cs) (like in [MyCustomProtocol](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/master/samples/ServerApplication/MyCustomProtocol.cs)) which internally passes `Input` of the `Transport` of `ConnectionContext` to constructor of [ProtocolReader](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/982f8f7fc97bac983cea297d84bacdd4530e1535/src/Bedrock.Framework/Protocols/ProtocolReader.cs). The implementation of `ConnectionContext` should be [SocketConnection](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/982f8f7fc97bac983cea297d84bacdd4530e1535/src/Bedrock.Framework/Transports/Sockets/SocketConnection.cs). The property Transport is of type `IDuplexPipe` and is created in `SocketConnection.StartAsync` which creates a [DuplexPipePair](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/982f8f7fc97bac983cea297d84bacdd4530e1535/src/Bedrock.Framework/Infrastructure/DuplexPipe.cs) and saves its property `Transport` to `SocketConnection.Transport` (see property `Transport` of [SocketConnection](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/blob/982f8f7fc97bac983cea297d84bacdd4530e1535/src/Bedrock.Framework/Transports/Sockets/SocketConnection.cs)). The type of `Transport` has `Input` and `Output` and are both of type [Pipe](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/Pipe.cs). This class uses [PipeAwaitable](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/PipeAwaitable.cs) internally in implementation of `System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync` (see method `ReadAsync` of type [Pipe](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/Pipe.cs)) by calling `BeginOperation`  of [PipeAwaitable](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/PipeAwaitable.cs). Finally, this method calls first time `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` of the token you passed initially by `var result = await reader.ReadAsync(protocol, cts.Token);`.

So your cancellation token is only get ignored when your cancellation has not been cancellation requested in the moment the very one code passage [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b8b81a66738bb10ef0790023598396861d92b2c4/src/System.IO.Pipelines/src/System/IO/Pipelines/PipeAwaitable.cs#L50) could pass.

> also the result.Cancelled is always false.

Your result is *not* a Task. When you create a Task manually (Task.Factory.StartNew) you can pass a `CancellationToken`. When this token gets cancellation requested before or after task creation then Task.IsCanceled will become true unless already finished (see [Task.AssignCancellationToken](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L670)).

But you have maybe recognized that you get not Task but ValueTask. This a lightweight task implementation to reduce Task creation overhead. This does not accept any `CancellationToken`. So your initial passed `CancellationToken` won't be used to notify `ValueTask` being canceled. In other words. As soon as the `ValueTask` gets created, the cancellation from `CancellationTokenSource` won't turn `ValueTask.IsCanceled` to true anymore. Only its internal held variable and if of type Task or IValueTaskSource and its implementation of Task.IsCanceled or `IValueTaskSource.GetStatus` can change this, but this is not the case (see next paragraph).

ValueTask accepts either any "precalculated" value, a `Task` or a "task"/promise that implements IValueTaskSource. In case of a value that implements IValueTaskSource, the only way to indicate `ValueTask.IsCanceled = true` is when `IValueTaskSource.GetStatus` returns `ValueTaskSourceStatus.Canceled`.
So `ReadAsync` from `Pipe` returns either the synchronous result wrapped by ValueTask or still pending/promised result also wrapped by ValueTask and this is important, this pending/promised result will be an internal variable of type `Pipe` that has been initialized in constructor of the public class `Pipe`. But your initially passed cancellation token in context of `Pipe.ReadAsync` is *not* interacting with the internal variable of type `Pipe` (implements `IValueTaskSource`) to get its implemented method `IValueTaskSource.GetStatus` to return `ValueTaskSourceStatus.Canceled`.

So the reason that your task won't never become true is that in no branch a `Task` with your initial cancellation token is ever created nor a `IValueTaskSource` implementation is implemented that is interacting with your initial passed cancellation token.

**So what are the consequences?**

When calling ReadAsync after your token has been cancellation requested, you are fine - you get your desired `OperationCanceledException`. After that you're are not covered by expected cancellation behaviour. So that's where you have to start to implement a solution by yourself:

```
        public Task ReadAsync() =>
            // This is just an example.
            Task.Delay(int.MaxValue);

        public async Task DoTaskNotForever(CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            using var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
            cts.CancelAfter(2);
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            using var registration = cts.Token.Register(() => tcs.SetCanceled());

            while (true) {
                try {
                    await Task.WhenAny(ReadAsync(), tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false);
                } catch (OperationCanceledException error) { 
                    // Ensure to flush/close/reconnect socket !!! (see below why)
                }
            }
        }
```

Before you use the above... I can only advice you to use the library https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx. Especially [Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/) and the Task extension method [WaitAsync](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs).

It is something like: `Tasks.WhenAny(theActualTask, throwOnCancellationRequestedTask)` where `throwOnCancellationRequestedTask` looks continously for cancellation request and throws if so:

```
using using Nito.AsyncEx;

...

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(2000);

        // this should throw if nothing is received after 2 seconds.
        var result = await reader.ReadAsync(protocol, cts.Token).WaitAsync(cts.Token); 

        if (result.IsCompleted || result.IsCanceled)  // this should hit
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Broke or cancelled");
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) // should get fired after 2 seconds unless ReadAsync has not yet finished
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
        break;
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Advance();
    }
}
```

**"Ensure to flush/close/reconnect socket !!!"**

After timeout cancellation by `WaitAsync` (that from Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks) or your own implementation, you should recreate the socket, or implement a safe prodecure that ensures that the finished or still running ValueTask from ReadAsync gets "finished". In SerialPort you can flush the `SerialPort.BaseStream` so the `Task` you got from `SerialPort.ReadAsync` gets "finished".

Comment: Let me check locally and report back, Thanks a lot for your answer.